# Roslyn, get containingAssembly in a consistent way

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis, static-code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I would like to extract as much information as possible about the dependencies of entities in a project using the relative *SyntaxTrees* and *SemanticModels* (and possibly the *Compilation* object).

One of the fields I'm interested in is the entity assembly, as this is necessary to locate and organise the files. As the SemanticModel allows to get the ContainingAssembly field, it seemed pretty straightforward:

[Trying to get the ContainingAssembly from Dictionary we obtain the right one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsyOu.jpg)

Other times though it doesn't go as planned:

[Result obtained calling the function on a ClassDeclarationSyntaxNode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJKYS.png)

Here is my theory: while in the first case the Compilation has a reference to the entity dll (*mscorlib* has been fed to the Compilation object), it can easily get the assembly *Dictionary<>* belongs to; in the second case we only have a bunch of SyntaxTrees added to a Compilation object and this leads to an approximate AssemblyName, that is the name of the project (CodeAnalysis) + Compilation.

Is there a workaround that allows me to obtain always the right assembly?